# Identifying many-to-many joins within two ID columns in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, many-to-many

I have a Pandas dataframe, df, with two columns of IDs. Buried within these two columns are sets of many-to-many matches, as per the below example:

```
ID1         ID2

001         003
001         004
002         003
002         004
```

I'm after a proficient way to identify these blocks, and to return the 'first to first', second to second' etc matches - in the above example, mapping 001 to 003 and 002 to 004 (although this isn't critical - it could return 001 to 004, and 002 to 003).

create dataframes

```
 l1 = ['001','001','002','002']
 l2 = ['003','004','003','004']
 df  = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2)),columns=['ID1','ID2'])
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID1','ID2'])
```

populate second dataframe with ID1, and the tuple of corresponding ID2 values

```
 for i in df[df.ID1.duplicated()]['ID1'].to_list():
     df2 = df2.append({'ID1':i, 'ID2':tuple(df[df['ID1']==i]['ID2'])}, ignore_index=True)

   ID1         ID2
0  001  (003, 004)
1  002  (003, 004)
```

Group by tuples, and create an ID1 tuple where the ID2 tuples are equal

```
df2.groupby('ID2')['ID1'].apply(tuple)

ID2
(003, 004)    (001, 002)
```

This gives me what I am after, but it's messy and embarrassing and it's only any good if nobody is looking. My pandas isn't brilliant - I wonder, are there any sharper tools for the job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reformat your code

Comment: Sorry. Let me work out what I need to do.

Comment: why you did not use `groupby.agg(tuple)` instead of the loop `for`, so try this `df.groupby(['ID1'])['ID2'].agg(tuple).reset_index().groupby('ID2')['ID1'].apply(tuple).reset_index()`. note that you might want to sort on ID2 first to ensure that tuple are ordered the same way

Comment: If you have a new line 001 005, what is the expect output?

Comment: Ben T, thanks for the suggestion, I will make that change, and the comment to sort is also appreciated.

Comment: Corralien - I didn't go into detail in my question as this is just a simplification of my data, but if 001 005 were there, there would also be 002 005, and another ID1 (say 006) with each or the values in ID2, increasing the rows from 4 to 9. In short there will always be a square number of rows to handle - but the vast majority of what I am dealing with are pairs, so only 4 rows.

However I totally accept that what I have done is a rather poor solution, and I was hoping there may be a smarter usage of a pandas function in the many-to-many realm - that's the essence of my question.